# Do Azure VM's have to use the same cloud service to be on the same virtual network?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a virtual network, and created a VM **woomph-live** and added it to the virtual network. This went off without a hitch.

I now want to create a 2nd VM **woomph-build** and add it to my virtual network. If I do this and select a *different* cloud service to the one **woomph-live** is using, creating VM fails.

However, if I choose the same cloud service as **woomph-live**, it starts fine. Is this correct behaviour? And if so, how do I access the website each VM is serving on port 80 on each VM?

Comment: When you say different cloud service are you talking about a different `Affinity Group`?

Comment: No, when you create a new VM using the gallery option, on the 3rd screen the first option is 'Cloud Service'

Comment: That is very odd, each VM should have its own cloud service.  It is through this that one is able to access the vm from the outside world.

Comment: That's what I thought, as it stand with both VM's using the same cloud service, I would have to use the IP address of each VM to access them. I obv don't want to do this as the IP changes every time the VM reboots.

Comment: What error message do you get when you give each VM its own cloud service?  The only time I've ever had a problem with cloud services was when i tried to create a new one, but it already existed.

Comment: I just tried it again and it's working now. Must have been something strange going on at Microsoft's side. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7):

When you create a virtual machine, you have to place it within a given cloud service (`mycloudservicename.cloudapp.net`). And multiple VM's may be placed in that cloud service. When creating the cloud service, you'll need to add it to a pre-defined virtual network. Once you do that, all VMs in the cloud service are automatically included in the VNet space. All VMs inside the cloud service are also able to talk directly with each other.

According to your question, you're then trying to create a VM in another cloud service. That cloud service would also need to be added to the same VNet as the first cloud service. You can then add one or more VMs to that new cloud service. At this point, the VMs in both cloud services have access to each other.

As far as your question about port 80: If you have a collection of VMs in the same cloud service, serving the same web site, then you can create a load-balanced endpoint on port 80, mapping to port 80 on your web server VM collection. If, instead, you want to access individual web servers, then you have to either:

- Place each web site on a different external port (assuming the web servers are in the same cloud service)
- Place each web server in a separate cloud service (then you can map each to port 80 externally)

Comment: Excellent information, particularly about the load balancing. I thought Affinity Group's were related to load balancing.